# Why this program work for some and wont work for others?

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to write some program, this program is for capitalize the first letter of each word in a sentence. And its work for some and some won't work, I don't know why, thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class javaexercises {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String a;
        char b[];

        System.out.println("Enter some word ");
        if(scan.hasNextLine()){
            a = scan.nextLine();
            b = a.toCharArray();
            b[0] = Character.toUpperCase(b[0]);
            for(int i=0;i<b[i];i++){
                if(Character.isWhitespace(b[i])){
                    b[i+1] = Character.toUpperCase(b[i+1]);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(b);
            scan.close();
        }
    }


}
```

When I input:

> q q q q q q q q q q q q q q q q

its gets:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 31
>       at javaexercises.main(javaexercises.java:15)

And when i input:

> dsad dwqdqw d qqw dqwqddqw dq dq wdq dq wdqd q dq wqd qw dq d

and its get:

> Dsad Dwqdqw D Qqw Dqwqddqw Dq Dq wdq dq wdqd q dq wqd qw dq d

The program stop capitalize letter after certain length?, I don't know.

Comment: You might notice that it throws an error every time the last character is a whitespace.

Comment: `for(int i=0;**i<b.length - 1**;i++){` - or similar (without the `**`, obvs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two small issues here, both noted in comments but felt to show you a demo in an answer.

**1)** If you have a space at the end of your input `String`, it will cause the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Change your input by using the `trim()` method; `a = scan.nextLine().trim();`.

**2)** You end your loop with `b[i]`, but should be `b.length()`.

`for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {`

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/ehhb2M)

Comment: I see, ty very much @notyou